# when i scroll down the tableview the checkmarks of the hidden cells disappear

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, checkmark

Cell with enabled checkmark before scrolling:

[image: cell with enabled checkmark before scrolling]

Cells with disabled checkmarks after I have scrolled up:

[image: cells with disabled checkmarks after i have scrolled up]

hey Guys, I have created a tableview and an add button to add new cells. when i add cells and i enable the `UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark` the checkmarks disappear when i scroll the tableview and the cells disappear out of the view.
how can i fix it ?

```swift
   var waterValue = [String]()


    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {




        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "add your amount of water for today", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(waterAmountTodayTF) in waterAmountTodayTF.placeholder = "enter L for today"})
        alert.textFields?.first?.textAlignment = .center
        alert.textFields?.first?.becomeFirstResponder()
        alert.textFields?.first?.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad


        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "add", style: .default) {
            (_) in
            guard let waterAmountForToday = (alert.textFields?.first?.text) else { return }
            self.add("\(waterAmountForToday) L")
//            print(self.sliderValue)
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }



    func add(_ individualWaterAmount: String) {
        let index = 0
        waterValue.insert(individualWaterAmount, at: index)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70.0
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return waterValue.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let individualWaterValues = waterValue[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = individualWaterValues
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark {
           tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        } else {
           tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        }
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        waterValue.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
```

Comment: First, make your tableview reuse cells instead of allocating new ones all the time. Second, don't store data in UI components, use your model objects for that.

Comment: so i should use dequereusablecell instead of UITableViewCell() ?

Comment: Yes, and also make your `waterValue` an array of structs that stores both your string and a "selected" value.

Comment: and what do you mean with "dont store your data in UI components" ? do you mean the UIbutton ?

Comment: Your code right now "stores" the selected state in the `accessoryType` of each cell. That's bad design, especially when you don't have as many cells as you have table entries. Like I said in my previous comment, store that information elsewhere. Usually is a good idea to have a struct that stores all data pertinent to a table cell, and use an array of those structs as the table's datasource.

Comment: hm okay im pretty new to swift snd xcode and right now im not so familiar with structs yet ^^

Answer (score 0):

You have not added logic to set accessory type to checkmark while creating new cell.

What you need to do is, save the value which you have selected, and then use that values while creating new cell.

```swift
var selectedIndexes: [Int] = []; //global variable
...
...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let individualWaterValues = waterValue[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = individualWaterValues
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
        cell.accessoryType = selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row) ? UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark : UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        return cell
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark {
           tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
           selectedIndexes.removeAll(where: { $0 == indexPath.row } )
        } else {
           tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
           selectedIndexes.append(indexPath.row)
        }
    }
```

Comment: it gives me an error behind the concerning the "?" in ```cell.selectionStyle = selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row) ? UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark : UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none```

Comment: checkout the updated answer. I miss placed `cell.accessoryType` in cellForRow method

Comment: tho when i scroll down and scroll up afterwards the checkmarks are in the view even though they have to be not visible